# What is $catList in depdrop - Kartik yii2 widget scenario 1?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, widget

I think I'm missing something with this example of the scenario 1 in the depdrop widget, this is the code:

```
/*
 * SCENARIO 1: A 3-level nested dependency example
 */
// THE VIEW
use kartik\widgets\DepDrop;

// Parent 
echo $form->field($model, 'cat')->dropDownList($catList, ['id'=>'cat-id']);

// Child # 1
echo $form->field($model, 'subcat')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
    'options'=>['id'=>'subcat-id'],
    'pluginOptions'=>[
        'depends'=>['cat-id'],
        'placeholder'=>'Select...',
        'url'=>Url::to(['/site/subcat'])
    ]
]);

// Child # 2
echo $form->field($model, 'prod')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
    'pluginOptions'=>[
        'depends'=>['cat-id', 'subcat-id'],
        'placeholder'=>'Select...',
        'url'=>Url::to(['/site/prod'])
    ]
]);

// THE CONTROLLER
public function actionSubcat() {
    $out = [];
    if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
        $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
        if ($parents != null) {
            $cat_id = $parents[0];
            $out = self::getSubCatList($cat_id); 
            // the getSubCatList function will query the database based on the
            // cat_id and return an array like below:
            // [
            //    ['id'=>'<sub-cat-id-1>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name1>'],
            //    ['id'=>'<sub-cat_id_2>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name2>']
            // ]
            echo Json::encode(['output'=>$out, 'selected'=>'']);
            return;
        }
    }
    echo Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'selected'=>'']);
}

public function actionProd() {
    $out = [];
    if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
        $ids = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
        $cat_id = empty($ids[0]) ? null : $ids[0];
        $subcat_id = empty($ids[1]) ? null : $ids[1];
        if ($cat_id != null) {
           $data = self::getProdList($cat_id, $subcat_id);
            /**
             * the getProdList function will query the database based on the
             * cat_id and sub_cat_id and return an array like below:
             *  [
             *      'out'=>[
             *          ['id'=>'<prod-id-1>', 'name'=>'<prod-name1>'],
             *          ['id'=>'<prod_id_2>', 'name'=>'<prod-name2>']
             *       ],
             *       'selected'=>'<prod-id-1>'
             *  ]
             */

           echo Json::encode(['output'=>$data['out'], 'selected'=>$data['selected']]);
           return;
        }
    }
    echo Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'selected'=>'']);
}
```

Whenever I try this it says that the $catList is an undefined variable, where that variable come from?
Assuming that I have a model/controller cat, sub-cat and prod and these are related.

If someone can guide me in the correct way it would be really helpful!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tipically is a list  of value that you want show in dropdown  list

```
 $catList=Category::find()->all();
```

or

```
  $catList  = ['a' => 'Item A', 'b' => 'Item B', 'c' => 'Item C'];
```

Comment: Ooh thanks a lot for this, one more question in the example this $catlist is generated automatically or I need to write first $catList=Category::find()->all(); in order to work?

Comment: in my answer  i mean that you must create your own $catList .. you should know from where   you obtain the value for  fill $catList .. ( you have an array? ... you have a table  with id, cat.id? ...